# Can't save Drupal role permissions for CiviCRM

Tags: drupal, permissions

After upgrading to CiviCRM 4.7.15 on Drupal 7.50 Commons, I am trying to enable some permissions relating to CiviCRM, such as "manage tags" and "edit message templates" but any changes I make to the permissions will not "stick" after I hit save. There is no error message and there doesn't seem to be any related error messages in watchdog show or CiviCRM ConfigAndLogs.

Any guidance to troubleshoot is appreciated.

Comment: does other core drupal permission gets updated properly ?

Comment: Permissions are stored in the drupal table *role_permission*. Can you find them there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Will permissions for non-civicrm related permissions "stick"? If not I've seen this problem before when there are too many roles/permissions on the form. Drupal commons installs a lot of modules, so its possible. You should either edit permissions for the roles individually, so for authenticated user for instance goto admin/people/permissions/2

I believe its the php.ini environmental variable max_input_vars and you should increase the number to get the full permissions form to work

Comment: That's right! if you have a number of roles and many modules that permissions form has a truckload of checkboxes. max_input_vars sounds right.

Comment: I tried editing permissions for just admin user and it timed out but it looks like the changes saved.

Comment: I don't know if you are hosting on Drupal Commons or just using their distribution.  Do you have access to modify your php environmental settings?  The real solution will be upping the max_input_vars ...